# Can you have a "meeting" with friends?

Tags: single-word-requests

"Meeting" (noun) sounds formal to me - correct?

"Meet-up" is defined as a informal meeting.

Is there a single word that can be used in both formal and informal situations?

e.g.

- I'm having a `[..]` with a business partner.
- I'm having a `[..]` with my friends.

---

Sorry if my question wasn't clear enough - I am looking for a noun.

Comment: I'm meeting my friends...

Comment: M-W implies there is: < **GET-TOGETHER**

:  meeting; especially :  an informal social gathering > but that 'meeting' would be more usual in the formal context. Indeed, business and pleasure [don't seem to mix too well](http://thesaurus.com/browse/get-together).

Comment: @mplungjan Why don't you submit this as an answer (rather than a comment, I mean)?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - would you say get-together is more commonly used than meet-up?

Comment: I can't find reliable evidence (Ngrams don't exist), but my perception is that 'get-together' has been far more common here in the UK through the last third of the 20th Century, though 'meet-up' is perhaps gaining ground nowadays. Certainly, verbal 'meet up' is pretty common nowadays.

Comment: I think you could have a rendezvous in either situation. Technically a tryst is just a prearranged meeting, but I think we can agree that it would be a bad idea to choose this word.

Comment: The Religious Society of Friends (the Quakers) use 'meeting' as the name for their act of worship. That is one does not attend a Quaker _service_, one attends a _meeting for worship_. Since the Friends were founded in the 17th century when joint stock companies were still quite new in England I suspect that the terms 'meeting for worship' and 'business meeting' were derived from an existing use of 'meeting' which was much more general. Indeed I'm sure I remember my parents talking about 'business meetings' rather than just 'meetings' in the 1950s and 60s.

Answer (score 2):

I would personally use

> I'm meeting my friends

or

> I'll meet my friends

Comment: I guess my question should have been clearer - I am looking for a noun. Any ideas? thanks.

Comment: Note that even here there's a register difference between business in pleasure. You _meet_ your friends, but in my experience you're more likely to _meet with_ clients or colleagues.

Comment: This is a good answer because it's simple and straight to the point.

Comment: Bradd Szonye. I think *meet with* is more likely in American English.